ba xr8 5 speed manual ford falcon 5.4 ecu replacement new vin number
I had a used ecu installed and programmed into my ford falcon ba 1 xr8 5 speed manual and it runs well. When I plugged in my sct x4 flash programmer it now shows a different vin number. The last few digits are different. I am wondering if this will be an issue when getting a new performance tune written or if the tuner can just use the new vin number shown?
